# How can I forcefully make useSubmit to trigger action without checking anything

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**react-router-dom v6**
When I am submitting action by get method like

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!standardSelected) return;
    clearTimeout(sectionListTimeOutId);
    const clearTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('>>> use submit called');
      submit({ standard_id: standardSelected }, { method: 'get' });
    }, 1000);
    setSectionListTimeOutId(clearTimeoutId);
  }, [standardSelected]);
```

My action function not getting  triggered, as action only triggered for method other than "GET" method.
**How can I forcefully make useSubmit to trigger action without checking anything.**

Comment: This question is missing a lot of code. Please post what url your trying to reach, including the route setup, etc.  Actions should work with both get and post.

Comment: Straight from the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/form#get-submissions): "Get submissions *will not call an action.*". It appears as though this is by design. Can you [edit] to clarify the use case and provide a more complete [mcve] so it's clear to readers what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger an action forcefully, you can use `"post"` method instead of `"get"`

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!standardSelected) return;
    clearTimeout(sectionListTimeOutId);
    const clearTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('>>> use submit called');
      submit({ standard_id: standardSelected }, { method: 'post' });
    }, 1000);
    setSectionListTimeOutId(clearTimeoutId);
  }, [standardSelected]);
```

Comment: This does not answer my question as I am submitting multiple req in once route, I need to submit by get method.

Comment: @Divya is it compulsory to use "useSubmit" or can you change it?